# Function calling within objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I have a object in javascript and I am going to call its *weeklyTargetConstraint()*.   Problem is that it will call a method *displayWeeklyTargetPrompt()*,  but this will not carry the object reference in the method call.

Why is the console printing out the Window object?  And how am a suppose to do this properly?

```
function main() {
     c = new Constraints(5,6);
     c.weeklyTargetConstraint();  
}


function Constraints(weekNum, dayID) {
     //setup
}    

Constraints.prototype = {
    weeklyTargetConstraint: function () {
        var state = $("#hfWeeklyFillOverride", weekNumber).val();
        this.constraintQty(this.fillTarget, state, this.displayWeeklyTargetPrompt);
    ///this will call displayWeeklyTargetPrompt()...
    },
    displayWeeklyTargetPrompt: function () {
        console.log(this);               // this is the Window Object
        console.log(this.weekNumber);    // its a input with id = weekNumber
        loadWeeklyFillTargetMsg(this.weekNumber);
        $('#weeklyTargetConfirm').dialog('open');
    },
// other stuff here
}
```

Comment: In a nutshell: `this.constraintQty(..., this.displayWeeklyTargetPrompt.bind(this))`

Comment: Also a duplicate of [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/218196)

Comment: Thanks did not know how to word this post